# Magento 2.2. Customer Custom Attribute

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, php-7

I want add bonus to my customer, in the internet i read that i need use custom attribute.

### etc/Module.xml

```
<module name="Kt_Addbonus" setup_version="1.2.2">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Customer"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

### Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;



class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

 /**
 * @var CustomerSetupFactory
 */
private $customerSetupFactory;
/**
 * @var AttributeSetFactory
 */
private $attributeSetFactory;


public function __construct(  CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
                              AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory)
{

    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}


/**
 * Installs data for a module
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $setup->startSetup();

    $attributesInfo = [
        'customer_bonus' => [
            'label' => 'Customer Bonus',
            'type' => 'int',
            'input' => 'text',
            'position' => 1000,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,

        ]
    ];

   $customerEntity =$customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
   $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultGroupId();

    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }


    $customerBonusAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_bonus');
    $customerBonusAttribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms'=>['adminhtml_customer']
    ]);

    $customerBonusAttribute->save();
    $setup->endSetup();

}
}
```

Custom attribute dont add to db or admin`s create customer page.
And PhpStorm says me that CustomerSetupFactory undefind, i already tried

```
setup:di:compile
setup:upgrade and cache:flush
```

did too.

### Update 1

CustomerSetupFactory was generated. But custom attribute still not added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please confirm that have you created registration.php on your module root folder like :

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Kt_Addbonus', __DIR__
);
```

Also replace following code into your InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Kt\Addbonus\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "customer_bonus");

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);


        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_bonus', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Customer Bonus',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'system' => false,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_bonus')
                ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms'=>['adminhtml_customer']
        ]);

        $attribute->save();

        $installer->endSetup();
    }

}
```

After above you have to run your extension again you need to remove your extension entry from setup_module table also then run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Thanks

Comment: Means attribute is not created or you got any error ?

Comment: attribute is not created, i have no any error

Comment: oh no im sorry, its work, your answer added customer_bonus attribute to  eav_attribute and customer_eav_attribute tables, thank you very much.

Comment: @HardikPatel, how to add two attributes,?

Answer (score 1):

I think your missing `namespace` in your setup script,

```
<?php
namespace Kt\Addbonus\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Customer Bonus',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' =>999,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],//you can use other forms also ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your  answer,  unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: what error coming same?

Comment: @newakkoff check this https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html

Comment: thank you, but i already tried all guides in internet)

Comment: @newakkoff https://mage2gen.com/ try this extension creator. Create the extension and update it. This extension will give clear definition for you..

Comment: yes i created this module right there

Comment: @newakkoff try my updated answer

Comment: tried, but did not help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not easily use custom customer attributes in Magento 2 community edition.
It's a paid feature in Enterprise Edition.

You can add it programmatically but in my opinion they done a lot to make it as difficult as possible.

See this thread for reference:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6575

Comment: thanks if it's a paid function, then it's better to add a column to customer_entity,  right? and extend CustomerInterface, Can I do that?

Comment: However you do it, you have to extend and overwrite a lot of stuff backend and frontend wise to make it work. See the linked thread or maybe look at an extension that does it. If you are not deep in the topic and do not want to dive deep. I'd rather suggest using an extension.

Answer (score 0):

I created a module that allow to add customer/address attribute from backend [here](https://github.com/danielmagestore/magento2-customer-attributes)

Maybe someone else will need it.