# Magento 2. change customer custom attribute value from plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin, php-7

[Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216104/magento-2-2-customer-custom-attribute) first question of mine.
Now i added custom attribute to my customer following this code

### InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Kt\AddBonus\Setup;

 use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
 use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
 use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
 use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
 use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

const BONUS_ATTRIBUTE_CODE = 'customer_bonus';


/**
 * @var CustomerSetupFactory
 */
private $customerSetupFactory;
/**
 * @var AttributeSetFactory
 */
private $attributeSetFactory;


public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
                            AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory)
{

    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}


/**
 * Installs data for a module
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute( Customer::ENTITY, self::BONUS_ATTRIBUTE_CODE, [
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Customer Bonus',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'system' => false,
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute( Customer::ENTITY, self::BONUS_ATTRIBUTE_CODE)
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms'=>['adminhtml_customer']
        ]);


    $attribute->save();
    $setup->endSetup();

}
}
```

And now i need Plugin which will change custom attribute value to 1000.

this is what i have:

### etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface">
<plugin name="bonusPlugin" type="\Kt\Addbonus\BonusPlugin"/>
</type>
</config>
```

### Plugin\BonusPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Kt\AddBonus\Plugin;



use Kt\AddBonus\Setup\InstallData;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;

class BonusPlugin
{
 public function beforeSave(CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
                           CustomerInterface $customer)
{
    $customer->setCustomAttribute(InstallData::BONUS_ATTRIBUTE_CODE,1000);
 }

}
```

when i press "Create An Account"  it just reset password fields in registration form and remains on this page, with the "we cant save Customer" error.
How i can create this plugin? And what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

**etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement">
   <plugin name="bonusPlugin" sortOrder="10" type="Kt\Addbonus\Plugin\BonusPlugin"/>
</type>
```

**Plugin\BonusPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Kt\Addbonus\Plugin;


use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement;

class BonusPlugin
{
    public function beforeCreateAccountWithPasswordHash(AccountManagement $subject,CustomerInterface $customer, $hash, $redirectUrl)
    {
        $customer->setCustomerBonus("1000");
        return [$customer, $hash, $redirectUrl];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it dont work, have same trouble.

Comment: Did you cleared the cache after update the new code? Check log files for error if any

Comment: i checked it, and magento log files and Nginx log files, did not see there something helpful

Comment: yes after update code i changed module version -> setup:upgrade -> cache:clean